# Prove linear independence of vectors transformed by linear transformation implies original vectors independent

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Let $v_1, ..., v_n$ be vectors in a vector space and let $T: V \rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation. Prove $\{T(v_1), ... T(v_n)\}$ linearly independent $\Rightarrow \{v_1, ... v_n\}$ linearly independent.

First of all, $\{T(v_1), ... T(v_n)\}$ linearly independent means:

$c_1T(v_1) + ... + c_nT(v_n) = 0 \Longrightarrow c_1 = ... = c_n = 0$

Note $c_1T(v_1) + ... + c_nT(v_n) = T(c_1v_1 + ... + c_nv_n)$

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Suppose $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} v_{i} = 0,$ where $a_{i}$ is a scalar for $i=1,\dots,n.$ Then, act with $T$ and see what you can conclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove it by contradiction. Note that $0$ does not belong to any set linearly independent, so you can rule out any of the vectors being null. If $c_1v_1 + ... + c_nv_n = 0$, where some scalar is non-null, say $c_1 \neq 0$, then we can write
$$  v_1 = \frac{-c_2}{c_1}v_2- \cdots\frac{-c_n}{c_1}v_n .$$

Applying $T$
$$  Tv_1 = \frac{-c_2}{c_1}Tv_2- \cdots\frac{-c_n}{c_1}Tv_n ,$$

Which Means that the set of images is linearly dependent.